# PHP - subtract dates on business days and working hours

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate the working hours between two dates. So I need saturday/sunday to be ignored and my working time is from 9am to 6pm (9:00 to 18:00).

I'v search the web and tried some variations, but nothing seems to be working. Any one can help?

I'v been looking at this links:
[Calculating working hours between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914360/calculating-working-hours-between-two-dates)
[subtract non working hours and days from two given times in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374275/subtract-non-working-hours-and-days-from-two-given-times-in-php)
[calc the working hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396562/calc-the-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

But or they didn't get the answer or the answer provided its not working.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted some functions on web and here on stackoverflow to my needs. Here they are.

Call script:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
$startDate=strtotime('2012-11-30 00:15:33');
$endDate = strtotime('2012-12-05 10:15:00');

echo "Working hours from create date until due date -> ".seconds2human(work_hours_diff($startDate,$endDate));
```

Place seconds readable by humans (adapted from http://snippetsofcode.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/php-function-to-convert-seconds-into-human-readable-format-months-days-hours-minutes/):

```
function seconds2human($ss) {
    $s = $ss%60;
    $m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
    $h = floor(($ss)/3600);

    return "$h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
}
```

Subtrack dates using business days and working hours (adapted from [Calculating working hours between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914360/calculating-working-hours-between-two-dates/)):

```
function work_hours_diff($date1,$date2) {
    if ($date1>$date2) { 
        $tmp=$date1; 
        $date1=$date2; 
        $date2=$tmp; 
        unset($tmp); 
        $sign=-1; 
    } else $sign = 1;
    if ($date1==$date2) return 0;

    $days = 0;
    $working_days = array(1,2,3,4,5); // Monday-->Friday
    $working_hours = array(9, 17.5); // from 9:00 to 17:30 (8.5 hours)
    $current_date = $date1;

    $beg_h = floor($working_hours[0]); 
    $beg_m = ($working_hours[0]*60)%60;
    $end_h = floor($working_hours[1]); 
    $end_m = ($working_hours[1]*60)%60;

    //In case date1 is on same day of date2
    if (mktime(0,0,0,date('n', $date1), date('j', $date1), date('Y', $date1))==mktime(0,0,0,date('n', $date2), date('j', $date2), date('Y', $date2))) {
        //If its not working day, then return 0
        if (!in_array(date('w', $date1), $working_days)) return 0;

        $date0 = mktime($beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n', $date1), date('j', $date1), date('Y', $date1));
        $date3 = mktime($end_h, $end_m, 0, date('n', $date1), date('j', $date1), date('Y', $date1));

        if ($date1<$date0) {
            if ($date2<$date0) return 0;
            $date1 = $date0;
            if ($date2>$date3) $date2=$date3;
            return $date2-$date1;
        }
        if ($date1>$date3) return 0;
        if ($date2>$date3) $date2=$date3;
        return $date2-$date1;
    }

    //setup the very next first working time stamp
    if (!in_array(date('w',$current_date) , $working_days)) {
        // the current day is not a working day

        // the current time stamp is set at the beginning of the working day
        $current_date = mktime( $beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n',$current_date), date('j',$current_date), date('Y',$current_date) );

        // search for the next working day
        while ( !in_array(date('w',$current_date) , $working_days) ) {
            $current_date += 24*3600; // next day
        }
    } else {
        // check if the current timestamp is inside working hours
        $date0 = mktime( $beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n',$current_date), date('j',$current_date), date('Y',$current_date) );
        // it's before working hours, let's update it
        if ($current_date<$date0) $current_date = $date0;

        $date3 = mktime( $end_h, $end_m, 0, date('n',$current_date), date('j',$current_date), date('Y',$current_date) );

        if ($date3<$current_date) {
            // outch ! it's after working hours, let's find the next working day
            $current_date += 24*3600; // the day after
            // and set timestamp as the beginning of the working day
            $current_date = mktime( $beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n',$current_date), date('j',$current_date), date('Y',$current_date) );
            while ( !in_array(date('w',$current_date) , $working_days) ) {
                $current_date += 24*3600; // next day
            }
        }
    }

    // so, $current_date is now the first working timestamp available...

    // calculate the number of seconds from current timestamp to the end of the working day
    $date0 = mktime( $end_h, $end_m, 0, date('n',$current_date), date('j',$current_date), date('Y',$current_date) );
    $seconds = $date0-$current_date;

    // calculate the number of days from the current day to the end day

    $date3 = mktime( $beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n',$date2), date('j',$date2), date('Y',$date2) );
    while ( $current_date < $date3 ) {
        if (in_array(date('w',$current_date) , $working_days) ) $days++; // it's a working day
        $current_date += 24*3600; // next day
    }
    $days--; //because we've already count the first day (in $seconds)

    // check if end's timestamp is inside working hours
    $date0 = mktime( $beg_h, $beg_m, 0, date('n',$date2), date('j',$date2), date('Y',$date2) );
    if ((!in_array(date('w', $date2), $working_days)) || ($date2 < $date0)) {
        // it's before, so nothing more !
    } else {
        // is it after ?
        $date3 = mktime( $end_h, $end_m, 0, date('n',$date2), date('j',$date2), date('Y',$date2) );
        if ($date2>$date3) $date2=$date3;
        // calculate the number of seconds from current timestamp to the final timestamp
        $tmp = $date2-$date0;
        $seconds += $tmp;
     }

    // calculate the working days in seconds
    $seconds += 3600*($working_hours[1]-$working_hours[0])*$days;

    return $sign * $seconds;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Try example from `2013-09-13 16:30:00` to `2013-09-14 21:00:00`; which is only one working day `2013-09-13` so result should be `1hour`, but it returns `9.5hours`.

Comment: Nice catch... Lets replace line if ($date2<$date0) { for if ((!in_array(date('w', $date2), $working_days)) || ($date2 < $date0)) {

Comment: I also placed $current_date += 24*3600; after the verification if it is a working day. Copy the entire function again and test on all scenarios you can remember.

Comment: Try 2013-09-21 23:11:47 and 2013-09-22 00:09:25, note that both these days fall inside the same weekend, the function returns a full day. It caused me quite some trouble but the solution I came up with is just to remove the if in `if ($days>0) $days--;`. Now this may create other unexpected results, so getting confirmation that this is indeed a proper solution would be nice.

Comment: Do not remove if ($days>0) $days--; Only remove the if condition. Script updated. But even if its working, its a mess, I promise when I have time I'll make my own from scratch with better logic and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is too late but i guess that this problem hasn't been solved yet, and i made a code that may help others with the same problem. This code just increase business days, so, it will skip lunch time, saturday and sunday.

```
<?php 
function recursivoHorarioComercial($data)
{
$hora =  date("H", strtotime($data));
if($hora >= 18){
    $arrHorarios = array('18'=>'15','19'=>'14','20'=>'13','21'=>'12','22'=>'11','23'=>'10','00'=>'9','01'=>'8','02'=>'7',);
    $minutes = (60 * $arrHorarios[$hora]);
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+".$minutes." minutes", strtotime($data)));
}
$diaSemana = date("l", strtotime($data));
if($diaSemana == "Saturday"){
    $extraMinutes = (2 * 24 * 60);
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+".$extraMinutes." minutes", strtotime($data)));
} elseif($diaSemana == "Saturday"){
    $extraMinutes = (1 * 24 * 60);
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+".$extraMinutes." minutes", strtotime($data)));
}
$horaFim = date("H", strtotime($data));
return $data;
}
function incrementMinutes($data,$minutes)
{
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$minutes = ($minutes % 60);
$hid = 8;
$days = floor($hours/$hid);
$horaINi =  date("H", strtotime($data));
$hours = $hours - ($days * $hid);
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+".$minutes." minutes", strtotime($data)));
$data = recursivoHorarioComercial($data);
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+".$hours." hours", strtotime($data)));
$data = recursivoHorarioComercial($data);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++){
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($data)));
    $data = recursivoHorarioComercial($data);
}
$horaFim = date("H", strtotime($data));
if($horaINi <= 12 && $horaFim >= 12 ){
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+60 minutes", strtotime($data)));
}
return $data;
}

$date = "2016-04-06 09:00:00";
$minutos =  24 * 60; //increase 24 hours
echo "Now: ".$data."<br />";
echo "<h2>Modified</h2>";
echo incrementMinutes($date,$minutos)."<br />";


?>
```

I've just tested this code and it is working fine. I hope that this may help anyone.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I tried to find the answer and spent a few hours creating my own, Im not saying its perfect, and if anyone wants to amend my code to make it cleaner please feel free. Still got a few things to change but it works. I have used the Carbon to assist with dates.

```
    function getWorkingHoursDifference($start,$end){


// Declare Business Hours Start
$BusinessHoursStart = '08:30:00';

// Declare Business Hours Start
$BusinessHoursEnd = '17:00:00';

// Set Full Day Span // *Need to Calc from above
$fullDayMinutes = 8.5*60;

// Declare Exclusions
$exclusions = ['Saturday', 'Sunday'];

// Declare Start Time
$TimeStart  = Carbon::parse($start);

// Declare End Time
$TimeEnd    = Carbon::parse($end);

// Create Start Date
$DateStart  = Carbon::parse(date_format($TimeStart, 'Y-m-d'));

// Create End Date
$DateEnd    = Carbon::parse(date_format($TimeEnd, 'Y-m-d'));

// Create Period Span
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($DateStart, $DateEnd);

// Create Period Array
$period  = $period->toArray();

// Set Day Counter
$dayCount = 0;

// Set Loop Counter
$loopCount = 0;

// Total Minutes
$totalMinutes = 0;


foreach ($period as $date) {$dayCount++;}

    // Debugging
        //echo '<table class="table"><thead><th>LoopCount</th><th>Period Date</th><th>Day</th><th>Day Start</th><th>Day End</th><th>Minutes</th></thead>';

        foreach ($period as $date) {

        $dayOnly        = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
        $dayOnlyName    = date_format($date, 'l');
        $dayStart       = Carbon::parse($dayOnly.$BusinessHoursStart);
        $dayEnd         = Carbon::parse($dayOnly.$BusinessHoursEnd);

                // Clean Minutes
                $minutes = 0;
                // Loop Counter
                $loopCount++;

                // Check Excluded Days
                if(in_array($dayOnlyName, $exclusions)){$minutes = 0;}

                // Check if its a single day
                elseif($loopCount == 1 && $dayCount == 1){
                    if($TimeStart < $dayStart && $TimeEnd > $dayStart && $TimeEnd < $dayEnd){$minutes = $dayStart->diffInMinutes($TimeEnd);}
                    // If the time start is after business hours then 0
                    elseif($TimeStart > $dayEnd){$minutes = 0;}
                    // If the time start is after start of the day, but before closing hours
                    elseif($TimeStart > $dayStart){$minutes = $TimeStart->diffInMinutes($TimeEnd);}

                }

                // First Day
                elseif($loopCount == 1){
                    // If the Time Start is before business hours, count as a full day.
                    if($TimeStart < $dayStart){$minutes = $fullDayMinutes;}
                    // If the time start is after business hours then 0
                    elseif($TimeStart > $dayEnd){$minutes = 0;}
                    // If the time start is after start of the day, but before closing hours
                    elseif($TimeStart > $dayStart){$minutes = $TimeStart->diffInMinutes($dayEnd);}
                }

                // Last Day (loopCounter Matches Total Day Counter)
                elseif($loopCount == $dayCount){
                    // If the Time is before the start of the business day
                    if($TimeEnd< $dayStart){$minutes = 0;}
                    // If the End Time is after the day end then full day is counted
                    elseif($TimeEnd > $dayEnd){$minutes = $fullDayMinutes;}
                    // If the End time is after the start but before the end of business hours, work out the difference
                    elseif($TimeEnd > $dayStart){$minutes = $dayStart->diffInMinutes($TimeEnd);}
                }

                // All other days in the middle
                else{$minutes = $fullDayMinutes;}

                // Debugging
                //echo '<tr><td>'.$loopCount.'</td><td>'.$date.'</td><td>'.$dayOnlyName.'</td><td>'.$dayStart.'</td><td>'.$dayEnd.'</td><td>'.$minutes.'</td></tr>';

                $totalMinutes = $totalMinutes + $minutes;

            }



        //echo '</table>';

        return $totalMinutes;
}
```