# Calculate number of days,hours,minutes,seconds only working hours

Tags: php

I have a php function to calculate timestamp (start date) to current (end) date that will return 1hr 30min 2s format. What I want to achieve is to calculate only from 8AM to 5PM of a working day. Anything that goes beyond will not be counted. Here is the php code I have.

```
class duration_computation {
   function duration( $time ) {
      $d[0] = array(1, "s");
      $d[1] = array(60, "min");
      $d[2] = array(3600, "hr");
      $d[3] = array(86400, "dy");
      $d[4] = array(604800, "wk");
      $d[5] = array(2592000, "mth");
      $d[6] = array(31104000, "yr");

      $numbers = array();

      $result = "";
      $now = time();
      $time_difference = ( $now - $time );
      $seconds_left = $time_difference;

      for ( $i = 6; $i > -1; $i-- ) {
          $numbers[$i] = intval( $seconds_left / $d[$i][0] );
          $seconds_left -= ( $numbers[$i] * $d[$i][0] );
          if ( $numbers[$i] != 0 ) {
          $result.= abs($numbers[$i]) . "" . $d[$i][1] . (($numbers[$i]>1)?'':'') ." ";
          }
      }
      return $result;
   }
}

$duration = new duration_computation();
echo $duration->duration($trail->duration);
```

---

Comment: This would be so much easier with a datetime object. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - subtract dates on business days and working hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655722/php-subtract-dates-on-business-days-and-working-hours)

Comment: So what is the outcome of your script?>

Comment: @putvande: he wrote `that will return 1hr 30min 2s format`

Comment: @Bora: that junk of code? Come on guys, make some nice DateTime examples ;)

Comment: @Glavić Questioner didnt search and efford. He can do this ownself and i just show him alternative. The function that on question already copied, not trying.

Comment: @Bore: still, it would be nice to see DateTime example for future OP's ;)

Comment: @JeBor: was the answer bellow OK?

Comment: i'm not finish modifying so i can't tell yet. little more time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `date(), strtotime(), time(), etc.` function, **use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)** :

#### Use example :

```php
$from = '2013-09-06 15:45:32';
$to   = '2013-09-14 21:00:00';
echo some_func_name($from, $to);
```

#### Output :

```
1 day, 22 hours, 14 minutes, 28 seconds
```

#### Function :

```php
function some_func_name($from, $to) {
    $workingDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; # date format = N
    $workingHours = ['from' => ['08', '00'], 'to' => ['17', '00']];

    $start = new DateTime($from);
    $end = new DateTime($to);

    $startP = clone $start;
    $startP->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $endP = clone $end;
    $endP->setTime(23, 59, 59);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $periods = new DatePeriod($startP, $interval, $endP);

    $sum = [];
    foreach ($periods as $i => $period) {
        if (!in_array($period->format('N'), $workingDays)) continue;

        $startT = clone $period;
        $startT->setTime($workingHours['from'][0], $workingHours['from'][1]);
        if (!$i && $start->diff($startT)->invert) $startT = $start;

        $endT = clone $period;
        $endT->setTime($workingHours['to'][0], $workingHours['to'][1]);
        if (!$end->diff($endT)->invert) $endT = $end;

        #echo $startT->format('Y-m-d H:i') . ' - ' . $endT->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "\n"; # debug

        $diff = $startT->diff($endT);
        if ($diff->invert) continue;
        foreach ($diff as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($sum[$k])) $sum[$k] = 0;
            $sum[$k] += $v;
        }
    }

    if (!$sum) return 'ccc, no time on job?';

    $spec = "P{$sum['y']}Y{$sum['m']}M{$sum['d']}DT{$sum['h']}H{$sum['i']}M{$sum['s']}S";
    $interval = new DateInterval($spec);
    $startS = new DateTime;
    $endS = clone $startS;
    $endS->sub($interval);
    $diff = $endS->diff($startS);

    $labels = [
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    ];
    $return = [];
    foreach ($labels as $k => $v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $return[] = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        }
    }

    return implode(', ', $return);
}
```

This function can be shorter/better; but that is your job now ;)

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to this problem and this is by far the cleanest solution out there! The only thing it doesn't seem to be able to handle is working hours of night shift workers, ie that span two days like 22:00 - 06:00. My current strategy is to breakup the hours into 2 days and run this function twice, however I was wondering if you had a cleaner solution?