# find time difference according to office timing

Tags: php, time

```
office timing : 10:00 to 19:00.
```

If a call is logged and is attended to i want to find the time difference between the logging and action completed only considering my office timing.
Like if a call was logged at `18:00` and the call was attended next day at `11:00` the total time should be `2hrs rather than 17hrs`..

I tried using `time()` function but all i was able to do was finding difference disregarding office timings.
Can anyone pls give me a hint or something??...
Thnx in advance!! :)

Comment: Hint - compute the amount of non-office time in the period, then subtract it from the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761978/67332) you have function example, that will calculate difference only in office time:

```php
$from = '2013-12-30 18:00:00 UTC';
$to   = '2013-12-31 11:00:00 UTC';
echo some_func_name($from, $to); # 2 hours
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/84186)</kbd>